# How do I divide a list of LI's with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, sorting, html-lists

Let's say my `Rails 3` app returns a list of `li` tags.  Think of an image gallery where each `li` tag contains a small image.

What I want to do is determine the width of the screen, then only show 5-7 images before I move down to the next line.

For example, say I have a wide-screen monitor I might have:

```
IMG1 IMG2 IMG3 IMG4 IMG5 IMG6 IMG7
IMG8 IMG9 ...
```

But on a smaller monitor, I would want:

```
IMG1 IMG2 IMG3 IMG4 IMG5
IMG6 IMG7 IMG8 IMG9 ...
```

Maybe JavaScript isn't the best way to do this.  Would it be better to write some method in Rails?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably just use CSS for this issue. Make the LIs float: left and they adapt to the space available.

Answer (score 1):

Using CSS only, you could set the `<li>` elements to `display: inline`, and then use relative widths (percentages) to make them fill the space. To change the number of elements per line, `@media` queries will help:

```
li {
    display: inline;
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
    li {
        width : 33%;  /* three per line */
    }
}
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    li {
        width : 25%; /* 4 */
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1000px) {
    li { 
        width : 20%;
    }
}
```

there will be other styles you'll have to reset to make that work exactly right (removing padding, etc), but that might be a good start.

Comment: This looks interesting.  Can't try it just yet but does that `@media` element work in all browsers?  Never heard of that method.

Comment: Looks like all the normal browsers, and IE9+ support it: http://caniuse.com/#search=media

Comment: However! Don't let that stop you from using this technique! Set a decent width for your items in the regular definition (say, 25%) and then override it with more appropriate ones using `@media`. IE8 and below will still show the items inline, but they will always take 25% width. It's definitely not a show-stopper (well, at least I hope so, in your case)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with CSS easily, set all the elements to 
    display:inline;
Put them all in a  with a percent based width (or just use the entire width)